# Is it possible to plot the coefficients from multiple brms models on a single graph?

Tags: r, bayesian

I know that this is possible with other types of models (e.g., [this](https://gist.github.com/dsparks/4332698)), but I haven't come across this for a model fit with "brms".

Has anyone had luck plotting the coefficients of multiple models, with different DVs, that were fit through brms?

Edit:

This is as far as I've gotten trying to use the method from that link for brms.

```
m1h<-fixef(mcmcm1_h1) 
m1e<-fixef(mcmcm1_e1) #these extract fixed effect info from a model fit with brms; below is an example of their output#

m1h
           Estimate Est.Error     2.5%ile  97.5%ile
Intercept 0.2615716 0.1482702 -0.01995366 0.5593722

m1hframe <- data.frame(Variable = colnames(m1h),Coefficient = m1h[, 1],SE = 
m1h[, 2],min = m1h[, 3],max = m1h[, 4],modelName = "HH")
m1eframe <- data.frame(Variable = colnames(m1e),Coefficient = m1e[, 1],SE = 
m1e[, 2],min = m1e[, 3],max = m1e[, 4],modelName = "Em")

allModelFrame <- data.frame(rbind(m1hframe, m1eframe))

library(ggplot2)
zp1 <- ggplot(allModelFrame, aes(colour = modelName))
zp1 <- zp1 + geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = gray(1/2), lty = 2)

zp1 <- zp1 + geom_linerange(aes(x = Variable, ymin = min,ymax = max),lwd = 1, 
position = position_dodge(width = 1/2))

zp1 <- zp1 + geom_pointrange(aes(x = Variable, y = Coefficient, ymin = min, 
ymax = max,lwd = 1/2, position = position_dodge(width = 1/2),shape = 21, fill 
= "WHITE"))

zp1 <- zp1 + coord_flip() + theme_bw()

zp1 <- zp1 + ggtitle("two models")

print(zp1)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type PositionDodge/Position/ggproto. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

Comment: What's in `allModelFrame`? Your error seems to indicate it _doesn't_ have a column called `Variable` in it.

Comment: Ah thanks! I'dbeen missing the line that combined them. I added it. I now get the following error:

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type PositionDodge/Position/ggproto. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket from the `aes` in `geom_pointrange`. It should be after `ymax = max` rather than at the end of the geom.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler solution using `broom`:

```
multiplot <- function(x) { 
    x %>% purrr::map(function(.) { 
             broom::tidy(., conf.int = TRUE, par_type = "non-varying") }) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "model") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(term, estimate, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = model)) + 
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) + coord_flip()
}
```

Use like this `multiplot(list(m1, m2, m3))`.